# Uncaught TypeError : self.showLocalNotificationWrap is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, async-await, web-push

So I am trying to send a notification using web push and it just does not work.
I see the event gets received but no notification shows up.

Here is the code for the 'push' event in my service worker:

```js
self.addEventListener('push', async (event) => {
    console.log("Push received data - ", event.data.text());
    const pushData = await event.data.text();
    let data, title, body;
    try{
      data = await JSON.parse(pushData);
      title = data.title;
      body = data.body;
    }catch(e){
      title = "untitled";
      body = pushData;
    }
    
    const options = {
      title : title,
      body : body, 
      icon : '/favicon.ico',
    }

    self.showLocalNotificationSW(title, body, self.registration);

})
```

And the `showLocalNotificationSw` the push event calls:

```
const showLocalNotificationSW = async (title, body, swRegistration) => {
    swRegistration.showNotification(title, options);
}
```

I see in the console it says `self.showNotificationWrap` is not a function in the console.
What does it mean?

I don't have any function named showNotificationWrap.

the error:

```
sw.js:48 Uncaught TypeError: self.showLocalNotificationWrap is not a function
    at sw.js:48
```

How do I fix this?

How do I fix this?

Comment: where are you assigning `self.showLocalNotificationWrap` to `self`?

Comment: Sorry, I am new to javascript. I don't know where I am doimg that.

Comment: yes - only you can answer that unless you provide a [mcve]

Comment: if you aren't doing that then thats the problem.

Comment: Yes i dont think i am assigning self to self.showLocalNotificationWrap

Comment: then thats your problem - you could drop `self.` or assign it

Comment: How do i assign it?

Comment: `self.showLocalNotificationSW = yourFunction`

Comment: still does not work

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231659/discussion-between-rag-and-daniel-a-white).

Comment: please post a [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I only needed to unregister and register the service worker again to fix the problem.

Here's the modified push event code:

```js
self.addEventListener('push', async function received(event) {
  let data, title, body;  
  data = event.data.text();
  console.log("Push received event - " + data);

    try{
      data = JSON.parse(data);
      console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
      title = data.title;
      body = data.body;
    }catch(error){
      console.error(error);
      title = "Undefined";
      body = data;
    }

    event.waitUntil(showNotificationSW(title, body, self.registration));

})
```